# Open session with id

Tags: php

I am in a situation that I got only sessions ID and I want to access all information present in that session. I m trying following at the top my script

```
session_id($_POST['SID']);
session_start();
```

Comment: Your context of execution should only have a handle to one session, and the data is in $_SESSION

Comment: Since you can access the `$_SESSION`, you likely don't actually need the session ID.

Comment: @Matt I am accessing php file via flash so no cookies are being passed. But server is same so I was thinking there might be some way to open session if I have a sessions ID

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. I'm not familiar enough with PHP to know if there's a way to get to the session without a proper session cookie. I _do_ know that you can't just set the session ID and call session_start(), though.

Comment: http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=11569

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)?

---

From the [YUI 3 Uploader](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/uploader/) Usage Notes:

> Because of limitations of the Flash Player, the Uploader does not transmit session data in the header of the POST requests it sends to the server. In order to transmit the session data, the developer will need to programmatically extract it from the DOM and send as part of the body of the POST request.

Are you doing that already?

Comment: @Ayaz yes, there's nothing in the session immediately after `session_start()`. What are you expecting?

Comment: But there is lots of data in session whose id i am trying to pass.

Comment: I have called session_start in previous files too. I am just reopening my previous session

Comment: @MattBall You have no idea what `session_start` does, do you?

Comment: @doug65536 please go on.

Comment: @MattBall Your comments seem to imply that session_start only creates a new session, when it actually starts a new session if one doesn't exist, or loads an existing session if one already exists. Obviously, the OP was "expecting" the data from the session for which he specified the ID. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

what you're doing is proper according to the docs if you want to override the session_id:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Then use the `$_SESSION` superglobal.

Note: you don't actually need to do this, since the id will be automatically assigned/read on session_start.

Comment: My situation is that I am using YUI flash uploader to upload files. At the server end one php file is handling uploads. Now when I open session my session become empty so I was thinking there might be a way to pass session id to open session.